# Почему мой код сильно избыточен?

Tags: python, python-3.x, чистый-код

Всем привет, хочу попросить Вас объяснить мне в чем у меня заключается ошибки и как его можно будет улучшать этот код. Вопрос был в *"Задача про зерна на шахматной доске на Python. Написать цикл, который бы выводил на печать порядковый номер клетки и количество зёрен на ней до тех пор, пока количество зёрен на одной клетке не превысит 100000. Используя простые циклы. While, for. Range. Помогите, пожалуйста."*

Вот код:

```
from math import *

sum = 0
for n in range(1, 65):
  m = int(pow(2, n - 1))
  print("%2d: %d" % (n, m))
  if sum < 100000:
    sum = sum + m
  if sum > 100000:
    break
print("sum = %d" % sum)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если так?

```
cell = 1
grains = 1
while grains < 10000:
    print("%2d: %d" % (cell, grains))
    grains *= 2
    cell += 1
```

Использование степени pow здесь не требуется, приведение результата к int вообще ни к чему. Два сравнения (причём не той величины, что нужна) - излишни.

Набор суммы по условию не требуется. Кстати, использование названия встроенной функции sum нехорошо.

Comment: О, именно такие 6 строчек кода, про которые я в том вопросе и писал в комментариях )

Comment: Спасибо что объяснил мне